# discord.js message.content for a word to send a message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
var rolledNumber = 0;
var norb = 'norb';
var thisPlace = 'this place';
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            // !ping
            case 'ping':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Pong!'
                });
            break;
            case 'commands':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'nope!'
                });
            break;
            case 'sleepydave':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'this is dave'
                });
            break;
            case 'roll':
                rolledNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'You rolled two dice and get: ' + rolledNumber
                });
            break;
         }
     }
     if (message.content[0,2000] == norb) {
         bot.sendMessage({
             to: channelID,
             message: 'Praise be to the Overlord'
         });
     }
     if (message.substring(0,2000) == thisPlace) {
         bot.sendMessage({
             to: channelID,
             message: 'stop talking about here'
         });
     }
});
```

This is my code

When "norb" is said as the only word, or "this place" is said, it'll work. But if it's between words like "hello norb hello" it won't work. Everything else is working fine for now.

I'd like it to look for "norb" and say "praise be to the overlord" when it's said. Rather than just when it's the first word. I'm not really sure how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some sample data like what `thisWord` is when this is working and what it is when it isn't as well as the values of `message`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to make the bot respond to a specific command. What you are looking for is the [`.includes()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) function

This function checks if a string includes the word you are looking for. For example:

```
const thisWord = "Something";
if(message.content.includes(thisWord))
{
    bot.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message: "Your reply."
    })
}
```

Comment: Whoops, yes @IsaacAbramowitz